# Comma separated column output into one plsql sproc

Tags: sql, oracle

SPROC should be compatible with versions lesser than 11g too..

created this procedure but it displays 2 rows for multiple column based indexes..which i want to display as one row with comma seperated values

Currently if i execute this on table(to get indexes information)..it displays me 2 rows for indexes(multi columns) but i would like it to return only one row per index..In case of multiple columns, the INDEX_KEYS column should reflect all the columns as comma separated list.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_1 (
    p_table_owner   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_result        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
    AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_result FOR 
SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys,
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type    
 from 
  (
  Select t.*,  
    row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by INDEX_NAME) as rn
    from 
    (
     SELECT      

        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
      --  di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' ) t      
)
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by index_name  = prior index_name
and rn = prior rn+1
start with rn =1 ;

End;
```

Comment: For comma separated lists take a look at LISTAGG (11g onwards): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 1):

> But i would like it to return only one row per index..In case of
>   multiple columns, the INDEX_KEYS column should reflect all the columns
>   as comma separated list.

You can try this in **Oracle 11g**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_1 (
    p_table_owner   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_result        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
    AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_result FOR 
   SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    LISTAGG (index_keys,',') WITHIN GROUP (    ORDER BY        index_name    ) "Index_Keys",
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type        
    from 
    (
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
                      FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
                      WHERE
       -- di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
        di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        partitioned = 'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
        --di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
        dip.composite != 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_subpartitions dis
        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
      --  di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' )       
       group BY index_name,index_description,INCLUDE_COLS,index_filter ,data_compression, allow_page_locks, table_name,index_type ;

END;
```

Note that i have used `table_name` as `'CON$'`. Replace it with your `table_name` with my name `table_name`

**EDIT:**

> any help on making it also work with 10g versions? just got to know
>   that we could also need it for it..

In **Oracle 10g** you can do as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_1 (
    p_table_owner   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_result        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
    AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_result FOR 
SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys,
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type    
 from 
  (
  Select t.*,  
    row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by INDEX_NAME) as rn
    from 
    (
     SELECT      
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
                      FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
                      WHERE
       -- di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
        di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        partitioned = 'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
        --di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
        dip.composite != 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT       
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_subpartitions dis
        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
      --  di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' ) t      
)
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by index_name  = prior index_name
and rn = prior rn+1
start with rn =1 ;

End;
```

Comment: Where in your code you see Create statement? As mentioned earlier close this question and ask clearly in another questiom what your requirement is. And make sure that unaccepting and accepted answer will not serve any purpose. That would inturn avoid us to reply your query. Be respectful to others who tke out time and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` and `GROUP BY`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id     NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE_NAME__ID PRIMARY KEY,
  value  NUMBER,
  other1 NUMBER,
  other2 NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT U_TABLE_NAME__OTHER1_OTHER2 UNIQUE ( other1, other2 )
);
```

**Query**:

*(Note 1: dbfiddle does not allow access to `dba_*` tables so the query below uses `user_*` tables instead with commented out sections appropriate for the `dba_` version.)*

*(Note 2: theredid not appear to be a functional difference between the output of your different `UNION`ed query so I removed the filters on `di.partitioned`. If there is a non-obvious difference then you can put them back and perform the `LISTAGG` grouping in an outer query.)*

```
select di.index_name as "INDEX_NAME",
       CASE WHEN di.index_type='IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered' ELSE 'nonclustered' END
       ||
       CASE WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique' END
       ||
       CASE WHEN cons.constraint_type = 'P' THEN ', primary key' END
       ||
       ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
       LISTAGG( ci.column_name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ci.COLUMN_POSITION ) as "INDEX_KEYS",
       null as "INCLUDE_COLS",
       null as "INDEX_FILTER",
       null as "DATA_COMPRESSION",
       null as "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
       di.table_name as "TABLE_NAME",                    
       case
       when di.index_type='IOT - TOP'
       then 'CLUSTERED'
       else 'NONCLUSTERED'
       end AS "INDEX_TYPE"
from   /*dba*/user_indexes di
       INNER JOIN /*dba*/user_constraints cons
       ON (    cons.owner = di.table_owner
           AND cons.table_name = di.table_name
           -- AND cons.index_owner = di.owner
           AND cons.index_name = di.index_name 
       )
       join /*dba*/user_ind_columns ci
       on ci.index_name = di.index_name
where  di.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
--and    di.table_owner = 'OWNER'
GROUP BY di.table_name, di.index_name, cons.constraint_type, di.uniqueness, di.index_type
```

**Output**:

```
INDEX_NAME                  | INDEX_DESCRIPTION                                    | INDEX_KEYS    | INCLUDE_COLS | INDEX_FILTER | DATA_COMPRESSION | ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS | TABLE_NAME | INDEX_TYPE  
:-------------------------- | :--------------------------------------------------- | :------------ | :----------- | :----------- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :--------- | :-----------
PK_TABLE_NAME__ID           | nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY | ID            | null         | null         | null             | null             | TABLE_NAME | NONCLUSTERED
U_TABLE_NAME__OTHER1_OTHER2 | nonclustered, unique located on PRIMARY              | OTHER1,OTHER2 | null         | null         | null             | null             | TABLE_NAME | NONCLUSTERED
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3745d4ed441846922e9990be1120470)*

Comment: @rock_techie Your entire problem is how to formulate the the SQL query within your procedure, this gives you the SQL query and you just need to replace the hard-coded table name with the PL/SQL bind variable's name and plug it into your existing procedure in place of your query (which needs no modification from a purely PL/SQL point of view).

Comment: And if you want to run it of legacy version of Oracle then there are multiple methods you can use to replace `LISTAGG` just search the internet for `Oracle 10g string aggregation` and you should get multiple hits.